# how to overlay GPX data on rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overlaying GPX data on rasters in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10932/overlaying-gpx-data-on-rasters-in-qgis)

When both layers are displayed in QGIS, they are not even visible in the same display. The coordinates displayed for each are wildly different and are not of the same magnitude. how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-project both your layers to a common coordinate system.

See `File`->`Project Properties`->`Enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation`

Comment: i did it but it can't. can you be more specific? do i need some other layers or to convert gpx file? please, could you explain me that with more details?